# Laravel Eloquent: Nested Query Builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, nested

Is there any way I could perfrom this DB query with Eloquent instead?

```
DB::table(DB::raw('(select * from threads order by id limit 20) th'))->orderBy('votes')->paginate(10)
```

Basically I want to order the threads by votes, but I don't want to request all the threads in the table for that, but only the 20 recent ones.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to get latest 20 threads and then sort them by votes, you could use [`sortByDesc()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sortbydesc) method:

```
$threads = Thread::latest()->take(20)->get();
$orderedThreads = $threads->sortByDesc('votes');
```

Comment: You forgot the paginate and OP didn't say he was using a Model for Thread ;)

Comment: Oh, I just forgot to. I am using a model for a thread of course.

Comment: But yeah, unfortunately this doesn't work with paginate() :(

Comment: Okay, I just used Laravel to manually build a paginator. Thank you Alexey!